# what is the difference between the .mask and .updateMask

Tags: google-earth-engine

```
var l8 =ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T2_TOA')

var landsat2016 = l8.filterDate('2016-01-01', '2016-12-31');

var median = l8.filterDate('2016-01-01', '2016-12-31').median();

// Load or import the Hansen et al. forest change dataset.
var hansenImage = ee.Image('UMD/hansen/global_forest_change_2015');

// Select the land/water mask.
var datamask = hansenImage.select('datamask');

// Create a binary mask.
var mask = datamask.eq(1);

// Update the composite mask with the water mask.

var maskedComposite = median.mask(mask);

var maskedComposite2 = median.updateMask(mask);
```

So what the difference between maskedComposite and maskedComposite2?

Answer (score 2):

In the way you apply the mask and updateMask, there is no difference. I would rather use updateMask, as this is written about the mask function:

> Note: the version that sets a mask will be deprecated. To set a mask
>   from an image on previously unmasked pixels, use Image.updateMask. To
>   unmask previously masked pixels, use Image.unmask.

Comment: So to answer @Graylemon question, are there cases where those functions are different? The documentation you cite is hard to follow... does it mean we should use `updateMask` when there's paradoxically no mask to update? And when should we use `mask` then? Thanks!!

Comment: There is no difference, except for that the function 'mask' will (somewhere in the future) be deprecated.

Comment: I think actually there is a big difference, see below?

Answer (score 1):

It seems actually there is a subtle but big difference between `mask` and `updateMask` when the original image on which the mask is to be applied itself contains masked values:

- `mask` overwrites the masked pixels in the original pictures: pixels that were masked in the original and "unmasked" in the mask get a value of 0
- `updateMask` respects the masked pixels in the original pictures: pixels that were masked in the original and "unmasked" in the mask remain masked

See the example below: original picture has masked out water. Second mask contains "unmasked" values for water. Output from `mask` or `updateMask` will be different! https://code.earthengine.google.com/8fe8a9dc1492aba1dc38f714ff759d65

[image]